# Check in a element in a directory is a directory or file

Tags: bash

I have a directory that contain a single item. How can I check if that item is a directory or a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stat -c %F yourItem
```

or use `file` to check: `file yourItem`

It will tell you if it is directory or file.

Comment: No, the situation is that I have a directory called Dir where there is one file or one sub-directory. My actual CWD is Dir and i want to know if the only item in Dir is a file or is a directory

Answer (score 0):

```
ll test/ | egrep "^d" | wc -l
```

This returns 1 if the item in the directory "test" is a directory or 0 if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1 is a directory";
elif [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "$1 is a file";
else 
    echo "$1 is not valid";
     exit 1
fi
```

Usage:

```
./test.sh /path/to/item
```